# Select Where Same Count

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do i count the number of papers with equal number of authors?

I wanna return number of authors, number of papers, sorted ascending by number of authors.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Papers(
  PKey INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Title VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
  Pages VARCHAR(64),
  CKey INT REFERENCES Conferences,
  JKey INT REFERENCES Journals,
  CHECK((CKey IS NOT NULL AND JKey IS NULL)
    OR (CKey IS NULL AND JKey IS NOT NULL))
);

CREATE TABLE AuthPapers(
  PKey INT REFERENCES Papers,
  AKey INT REFERENCES Persons,
  Rank INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(PKey, AKey),
  CHECK(Rank >= 1)
);

CREATE TABLE Persons(
  AKey INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  Website VARCHAR(256),
  IKey INT REFERENCES Institutions
);
```

How do I achieve this?

Result

[image: Result of SQL]

Comment: Please include sample data and desired results. "Count the number of papers with equal number of authors" is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I want to recieve as an output the number of papers which have the sane amount of authors. So if there are 5 Papers with 10 authors i wanna have as a result the amount of authors that have written thoose papers as well as how many papers have the exact same amount of writers

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output you desire?  I'm not clear on how it can both be the number of papers and the number of papers on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  AuthCount,
  COUNT(Pkey) as PaperCount 
FROM (
      select 
      PKey, 
      COUNT(AKey) as AuthCount 
      FROM AuthPapers 
      GROUP BY PKey) as t 
GROUP BY AuthCount 
ORDER BY AuthCount
```